# Returning previous record value for FieldB in current record for FieldB using DAX

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot, get-transform

This is really easy in Sxcel but I cant for the life of me figure out how to return a previous record value to the current record of that same field

```
FieldA
#2344          

FieldB
=IF Left([FieldA],1)="#", [FieldA], previous record value of fieldB
red
green
43
```

In Excel it would be a relative reference to the cell in FieldB which would then be incremented in the entire field - for example I would have:

```
FieldB
if (Left(A2,1)="#", A2, B1)
```

and then I would fill the entire table field for FieldB and the "A2" and "B1" would increment all the way down - I am not sure how to accomplish this in DAX because I want to create a column that does this and my dataset is more than 1 million records so cant do it in an excel tab

Comment: This code and data in this question is formatted so strangely that I have no idea what you are asking. Please consider reformatting.

Comment: Add an Index column in the Power Query import, then write a Measure using CALCULATE and FILTER?